# Validate Space with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regex `/^\pL{3,32}+$/u` to validate letters only from any UTF-8 language with the range of 3 to 15 letters. However I need to allow space to be pass the validation, how can I tweak that? so multi words will pass as well and keeping the length from 3 to 32 no matter how many words the string is.

Thanks

Comment: you can use \s character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^[\pL ]{3,32}+$/u
```

Comment: or `\s`, assuming all white spaces.

Comment: Yes, depending on whether he would like to allow all white spaces or just the space character.

Comment: Thanks alot @MaciejSz, whats the difference between white spaces and space character though?

Comment: White spacas can addtionally contain tabs, carriage return and other non-printable characters.

Comment: The above is equal to `" "`, whitespace in general includes tabs, line breaks, form feeds, etc..

Comment: oh thanks alot guys, i'm just looking for spacer character then, just to validate first and last name of the user.

Comment: I would include tabs to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

To allow all unicode space characters you should use regex pattern

```
/^[\p{L}\p{Zs}]{3,32}$/u
```

I would like to point out to your `+` in your pattern. Combining `+` with `{3,32}` actually leads into matching any length large than 2 of such characters.